# Is it possible to page up/down in Vim without moving the cursor?

Tags: vim, gvim

Is it possible to move to another page in gVim without moving the cursor from its present location?

Splits don't count :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the way that Vim functions internally (and also due to historical reasons) means that cursor must always be visible.

Comment: Yeah, suspected as much ... but just, thought I'd check ...

Answer (score 7):

I do not believe this is possible. You can, however, move the window relative to the current cursor position, while maintaining the cursor on the screen by using `zz` (move cursor to middle of screen), `zt` (move cursor to top of screen), and `zb` (move cursor to bottom of screen). In all of these cases, the cursor position is unchanged, while the window is scrolled around it.

Comment: This is basically the functionality I was looking for. I wish I could hold down a key so that my cursor stayed in the same spot and scrolled line by line with `jk`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible AFAIK.

The best you can do is drop a mark.

Or you can press `gi`. This will place you where you last were inserting text.